# What does "fortuitous with respect to viruses" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Page 154 of Secrets and Lies](http://books.google.com.sg/books?id=z_7CAjmql6kC&pg=PT161&lpg=PT161&source=bl&ots=NqBK6pA2To&sig=li6_Fw3JacOviSJZNoqRaM6xHvY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sCLiUrjOEenA0QXpzYHoAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) has this snippet:

> In some ways we've been fortuitous with respect to computer viruses;
>   all the ones we've seen are targeted against large computers, not
>   peripherals or embedded systems.

What does "we've been fortuitous with respect to computer viruses" mean?

Substituting "fortuitous" with it's literal meaning "accidental" does not make much sense; i.e. *We've been accidental with respect to computer viruses.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the person quoted mistook *fortuitous* for *fortunate.* Try re-reading with *fortunate* instead --- it should make more sense.

Comment: I've linked this thread in an email to Schneier (the author). This is his reply: "*I was thinking of the situation, but you're probably right.*"